# Como Retornar a declaração de um atributo em um JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

Sou iniciante em programação, minha dúvida é a seguinte:
  - Criei um atributo `public static final double Preco_Gasolina = 3.85`, em uma classe A.
 - Quero retornar o valor de `Preco_Gasolina = 3.85` em um `JLabel` na classe B.

Isso é possível, como faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na classe B, basta fazer assim:

```
myJLabel.setText(String.valueOf(A.Preco_Gasolina));
```

Como seu atributo é estático e publico, basta fazer a referencia a classe A e chamá-lo diretamente, fazendo a conversão de `double` para `String`, usando [**`valueOf()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)).

Comment: Amigo sua dica deu certo. Mas aparece uma incompatibilidade para converter de Double para String.

Comment: @EliveltonFrança perdão corrigi já. Se encontrar outro problema só falar :)

Comment: Bom!  Problema resolvido. Obg!

Comment: @EliveltonFrança que bom! :) se a resposta te atendeu, você pode marcar como aceita clicando no `v`, assim, servirá de referencia para outros com o mesmo problema;